# In year ARR (Annual recurring revenue) formula

Tags: formula

I am currently using this formula to calculate FY23 In Year ARR (Revenue expected to be earned during 2023):

```
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Production_Live_Date__c)) && 
YEAR(Production_Live_Date__c) == 2024 || 
Month(Production_Live_Date__c) == 12,0,
(11- month( Production_Live_Date__c ))*(List_price_MRR__c))
```

I now need to compile a formula for 2024 which also takes into account deals signed in 2023.

1. Any deal signed in 2023 where Production_Live_Date__c is in Jan-Nov, should be 12*List_price_MRR__c
2. Any deal signed in 2023 where Production_Live_Date__c is in Dec, should be 12*List_price_MRR__c
3. Deals where the Production_Live_Date__c is in 2024 should follow the logic of the original formula

HELP PLEASE

I've tried to build this out with a CASE function but getting errors:

```
Case (
Production_Live_Date__c,
ISBLANK, 0,
YEAR=2025,0
MONTH=12&&YEAR2025,11- month(Production_Live_Date__c )*(List_price_MRR__c),
MONTH=12&&YEAR2024,12*(List_price_MRR__c),
MONTH=11&&YEAR2024,12*(List_price_MRR__c),
MONTH=10&&YEAR2024,12*(List_price_MRR__c),
MONTH=9&&YEAR2024,12*(List_price_MRR__c),
MONTH=8&&YEAR2024,12*(List_price_MRR__c),
MONTH=7&&YEAR2024,12*(List_price_MRR__c),
MONTH=6&&YEAR2024,12*(List_price_MRR__c),
MONTH=5&&YEAR2024,12*(List_price_MRR__c),
MONTH=4&&YEAR2024,12*(List_price_MRR__c),
MONTH=3&&YEAR2024,12*(List_price_MRR__c),
MONTH=2&&YEAR2024,12*(List_price_MRR__c),
MONTH=1&&YEAR2024,12*(List_price_MRR__c),
NULL)
```

Comment: What are the errors?  Please [edit] your post to include the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use nested IF statements instead of CASE, try this.

```
IF(
    ISBLANK(Production_Live_Date__c), 0,
    IF(
        YEAR(Production_Live_Date__c) == 2025, 0,
        IF(
            YEAR(Production_Live_Date__c) == 2024,
            (12 - MONTH(Production_Live_Date__c)) * List_price_MRR__c,
            IF(
                YEAR(Production_Live_Date__c) == 2023,
                12 * List_price_MRR__c,
                0
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!